# OpenCL for-loop only working once

Tags: android, for-loop, opencl, video-processing

The program is an Android application and needs to progress an mp4 image. The initialization can be found in this question: [init code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696901/android-with-opencl-video-processing)

But I found out that the init code works with kernels who do **not** use `for` loops.
When I have a nested for loop as in the example on the bottom of the post, only the first image will be processed and all the others will be black.

Simple example:

```
1)
init function
execute kernel with for loops
remove opencl function
```

=> all goes fine

```
2)
init function 
execute kernel **without** for loops
execute kernel **without** for loops on next frame
remove opencl function
```

=> all goes fine

```
3)
init function
execute kernel **with** for loops
execute kernel **with** for loops on next frame
remove opencl function
```

**=> first frame is processed, 2th frame is black**

edge kernel:

```
__kernel void edgeKernel(__read_only  image2d_t  srcImage,
                          __write_only image2d_t  dstImage)
{    
    const sampler_t sampler = CLK_NORMALIZED_COORDS_TRUE |
                               CLK_ADDRESS_REPEAT         |
                               CLK_FILTER_NEAREST;
    int x = get_global_id(0);
    int y = get_global_id(1);
    int2 coords = (int2) (x,y);

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    float4 bufferPixel,currentPixel;
    float sum = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    const float edgeKernel[9] = {0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,1.0f,-4.0f,1.0f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f};
    currentPixel = read_imagef(srcImage,sampler,coords);
    for(i=-1;i<=1;i++)
    {
        for(j=-1;j<=1;j++)
        {
        coords = (int2)((x+i),(y+j));
        bufferPixel = read_imagef(srcImage,sampler,coords);
        //sum = sum + (bufferPixel.y * edgeKernel[counter]);
        sum = mad(bufferPixel.y,edgeKernel[counter],sum);
        counter++;
        }
    }
    if(sum>255) sum=255;
    if(sum<0) sum=0;

    currentPixel.x=sum;
    currentPixel.y=sum;
    currentPixel.z=sum;

    write_imagef(dstImage,coords,currentPixel);                           
}
```

**I can not see what's wrong, I guess it's something with overlapping memory allocation but I'm clueless on what the solution might be.**

**Edit1:**

[OpenCL code](https://github.com/degoossez/OVSR/blob/master/jni/OVSR.cpp) is the link to the OpenCL code. Look for the `initOpenCL` and `nativeImage2DOpenCL` function. You should be able to find everything you need there.

Comment: Are you waiting till the first one finishes before putting the second frame in memory? Since I don't see any reason why the kernel will not work in a 2nd run, since the code is ok, and it works for the first frame. I think your problem is how you run the kernels, not in the kernel itself.

Comment: If one frame is processed correctly, that means that kernel is ok. How are you getting frames from decoder?

Comment: DarkZeros: I've added a link to the OpenCL code. All the OpenCL code can be found there. If you need anything more specific, just ask and I'll provide.
Roman: the decoder should be right, if I try with my inverse kernel it processes everything. The problem only appears when I use a for loop in my opencl kernel.

Comment: I did not really solve it, not for all the cases (I have multiple filters that are called with the same code). I went to the OpenCL IRC channel (lot's of helpfull people there) and found someone (nick: sharpneli) who helped me debugging and we concluded that it must be the driver quality that is not 100%. So you can try and change things in your kernel and test again, with try and error and hope that you can find the kernel your driver likes the most. A good thing to try is to turn off all the compiler optimalisations. It helped my for one kernel..